# For $I:(X,d_1 )\to(X,d_2)$, $I(x)=x$, proving $I$ is continuous iff $\tau_{d_1}=\tau_{d_2}$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

> **Problem.**<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1pf.png)</sup> Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ two metrics. Let $I : (X, d_1) \to (X, d_2)$ be given by $I(x) = x$. Then is the following true?
>
> $$ \text{$I$ is continuous} \quad\iff\quad \tau_{d_1} = \tau_{d_2} $$

I tried to prove that like this:

$(\impliedby)$ : Let $\tau_{d_1} = \tau_{d_2}$. Let $x_0 \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. We know that $B_{d_2}(x_0, \varepsilon) \in \tau_{d_2} = \tau_{d_1}$. So, for $x_0 \in B_{d_2}(x_0, \varepsilon)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_{d_1}(x_0, \delta) \subseteq B_{d_2}(x_0, \varepsilon)$ and we know that $I(B_{d_1}(x_0, \delta)) = B_{d_1}(x_0, \delta) \subseteq B_{d_2}(x_0, \varepsilon)$. Then $I$ is continuous.

$(\implies)$ : Let $I$ be continuous. If $G \in \tau_{d_2}$, then $G = I^{-1}(G) \in \tau_{d_1}$ (because $I$ is continuous). Then $\tau_{d_2} \subseteq \tau_{d_1}$.

**Question.** Now I have to prove that $\tau_{d_1} \subseteq \tau_{d_2}$, but I don't know how can I do that?

Comment: I revised your question using MathJax and assuming you actually intended $Y = X$. Hope this is to your liking, or otherwise, please feel free to edit!

Comment: yes X=Y. I made a mistake while writing. I am sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having trouble since the claim you are trying to prove is false.  As a counter-example, let $X=\mathbb R$, let $d_1$ be the discrete metric $d_1(x,y)=1$ if and only if $x\neq y$, otherwise $d_1(x,x)=0$, and let $d_2(x,y)=|x-y|$.  Then the identity is continuous but the topologies are different, as the former (the discrete topology) includes every subset of $\mathbb R$, and the latter does not.

Note that in general, you ***can*** say that the identity is continuous if and only if $\tau_{d_2}\subseteq \tau_{d_1}$, which is essentially what you have already proved.

##### Remark

Note also that you can dispense with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ business in the first part of your proof and simply argue that if $\tau_{d_2}\subseteq \tau_{d_1}$, then if $G\subseteq X$ with $G\in \tau_{d_2}$, then $I^{-1}(G)=G\in \tau_{d_1}$, so the inverse image of every open subset is open, which is an equivalent definition of continuity that I presume you are aware of, since you used it in the second half of the proof.

As a result, once you formulate it correctly the result generalizes beyond metric spaces to the statement that if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$, then the identity $I:(X,\tau_1)\to(X,\tau_2)$ is continuous if and only if $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$.

Comment: Now I can understand. thank you very much.